# PostgreSQL Queries - Spree product filtering methods and associations

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, spree

I am trying to add some filtering to products, but my queries are pretty ugly and heavy..

How would you improve this query? *(want to return products that don't have a translation or have but field is blank)*

```
Spree::Product.all.map { |p| p if !p.translations.find_by(locale: 'en') || (p.translations.find_by(locale: 'en') && p.translations.find_by(locale: 'en').name.blank?) }.reject(&:blank?)
# takes about 1 second
```

Another query is about Taxons associated with Products:

```
Spree::Product.all.map { |p| p unless p.taxons.any? }.reject(&:blank?)
```

I know there is a way to return Records that don't have any associated `has_many` records, like: `Spree::Product.all.includes(:taggings).where(taggings: { taggable_id: nil })`. But for some reason it doesn't want to work with Taxons.

I wonder also if there is a way to improve queries on model methods. For example, I have a query that returns all the products that don't have images:

```
Spree::Product.all.map { |p| p unless p.all_images.any? }.reject(&:blank?)
# takes over 2 seconds

# product_decorator.rb
def all_images
  (images + variant_images).uniq
end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you use the `.all` it will load all the records and perform those operations you set inside the blocks(`{}`). Try to mount a query using pure `SQL` or even better, using the `.where` clause, it will mount your query and will perform better. You can use several `.where`, one after the other chaining the methods.

You can find more about conditions on the [Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#conditions)